Rentcharges under Leasehold and Freehold Reform Bill 2024
The Leasehold and Freehold Reform Bill includes Part 7 on estate rentcharges. (A "rentcharge" is an obligation on a freeholder to pay money to a third party known as the "rent owner". This is nothing at all to do with renting property as a tenant).
The 2024 act amends the Law of Property Act 1925 to create a "regulated" rentcharge, and limits the ways that the rent owner can enforce payment. But the definition of a "regulated" rentcharge is:

For the purposes of sections 120B to 122 a rentcharge is “regulated”
if it is of a kind that could not be created in accordance with section
2 of the Rentcharges Act 1977.

That section of the 1977 act stopped new rentcharges being created, with a few exceptions. The main exception is "estate rentcharges" where the money goes to maintain land which benefits the householder who has to pay, such as general landscaped areas around a housing estate.
So do I understand correctly that estate rentcharges are of a kind that could be created under the 1977 act, and hence are not "regulated rentcharges" under the 2024 reform act?
If so then it seems that Part 7 of the 2024 act has very little effect, since all other rentcharges have already been extinguished under Section 3 of the 1977 act, or will be by 2037. Have I got that right?

From paragraph 633 of the draft Explanatory Notes:

New section 120A (1) details that for new sections 120B to 122, a rentcharge is “regulated” if it is a rentcharge that could not be created under section 2 of the 1977 Act; it relates to historic rentcharges.

So if I understand correctly, your understanding is correct; and as you say, any such rentcharge will expire by 2037 at the latest.
As for why legislation has been enacted now, paragraph 55 of the Notes explains:

Failure to pay a rentcharge within 40 days of its due date means that [under section 121 of the Law of Property Act 1925], the recipient of the rentcharge (the rentcharge owner) may take possession of the subject premises until the arrears and all costs and expenses are paid, or the rentcharge owner may grant a lease of the subject premises to a trustee that the rentcharge
owner may set up themselves.
The proposals in this Bill seek to fulfil a public commitment made in December 2017 so that a rentcharge owner is not able to take possession or grant a lease on the property where the rentcharge remains unpaid for a short period of time.

